# display text on command window of matlab engine

Tags: matlab, matlab-engine

How to display the text on command window of matlab engine?
I used `engSetVisible` to make engine command window visible, but after I don't see any text in this window, how to do this?
I would not like to use `engOutputBuffer`, then handle this buffer. I just want to see output from `engEvalString` on engine command window

Comment: did you try to evaluate `disp(..)` or evaluate an expression without semicolon at the end?

Comment: Yes, I tried and disp(..) and expression without semicolon in the end

Comment: It should normally work. Please post your code, I'm guessing you're doing something wrong...